# Android NDK: native c++ instances in native c++ instance

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

Native C++ instance could be kept by native heap and reference it by jlong.
But does this instance also keeps other native instance that we used?

For example, 
if I created a C++ Vector2D class and I used it in C++ Mass class, and I've referenced only the Mass instance to jlong, does the instance of Vector2D still remains later like primitive type value?

If it does, can I presume that we can KEEP EVERYTHING we want in one complex nested C++ instance with just one jlong reference?

Comment: C++ does no garbage collection if thats what you are asking. You can leak everything as much as you want.

Comment: Don't add words like "unsolved" or "solved" to the title - Stackoverflow has that functionality built in through the answer and acceptance system.

Comment: In addition: if this C++ object is never passed back to Java, you don't have to store it as a `jlong`. Store it as a regular C++ pointer, i. e. `Mass *`. Or as a smart pointer, i. e. `auto_ptr<Mass>`; read up on those.

Comment: But if I don't pass jlong back to java then I can't retrieve the C++ object.